# Beginning list items with numerals

Tags: writing-style, numbers, lists

Most well-known style guides dictate that numbers should *always* be spelled out at the beginning of a sentence (*Forty-seven percent of people...*), even to the point of recommending rewriting to avoid spelling out awkwardly large numbers (*In all, 5,260 people...*).

I have a bulleted list of percentages in which I would really like to start all of the list items with numerals:

> - 12 percent of messages...
> - 50 percent of messages...
> - 19 percent of messages...
> - 4 percent of messages...

Spelling all the numbers out would significantly harm readability. Rewriting to put the numbers later would also harm readability, in addition to appearing contrived. I've checked my *Chicago Manual of Style*, but it doesn't seem to address this particular situation, or at least I haven't been able to find it.

Are there any commonly accepted sources that offer guidance on this point, or is it just too rare to have come up?

Comment: This is a good question, but unfortunately you won't get any satisfaction from _Chicago_ on this point. _Chicago_ offers only two guidelines: a sweeping endorsement of spelling out numbers at the beginning of a sentence (and I gather that each bulleted entry in your list is a complete sentence of the type "2 percent of messages are X"), and advice to rearrange the wording if you can't stand the spelled-out arrangement. There's no flexibility in the rule "When a number begins  sentence it is always spelled out." I'll check some other style guides, but they are unlikely to help much.

Comment: Are you trying to convince an editor that your style is acceptable?  That is to say, if you think it's more readable with numbers, why not just use numbers?

Comment: Don't use a list. Instead, use a table. Table columns and rows are often expected to contain numbers. And if you're presenting this kind of repetitive information, it will be more easily understood in a table format anyway. Repeating *percent of messages* many times is awkward. Tables are designed to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules for bullets don't always follow the rules for sentences. Your bullets are correctly written in my view.

Even *Chicago* wouldn't expect a recipe book to list ingredients as follows:

- three and a half cups sugar
- one hundred and fifty grams cocoa
- one eighth of a teaspoon salt